# In Firebase, is it possible to get data from the return of write function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, read-data

I want to get user data from the return of creating a user, as below:

```
const newUserRes = await db.collection('users').add(userData);
```

Do you have any suggestions for me to get the new user document straight away from `newUserRes`?

I don't feel right to call a new read to get it:

```
const newUserRef = await db.collection('users').doc(newUserRes.id).get();

const newUser = newUserRef.data()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `add()` method returns an asynchronous `DocumentReference`, which does *not* contain a snapshot of the data that was just written. So you will indeed have to read the document after writing it, just a you do in your second snippet.

Comment: I have tried and see that we need to first call: "await newUserRes.get()" before the second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to getting new user data directly from the write return (newUserRes)

```
const newUserSnapshot = await newUserRes.get();

const newUserData = newUserSnapshot.data();
```